# DJIGimbalAttitudeAction in Timeline mission

Tags: dji-sdk

i am trying Timeline mission. I created timeline mission with basic flow like:-

1. takeoff Action
2. DJIGoToAction()
3. DJIGimbalAttitudeAction()
4. DJIShootPhotoAction()
5. DJIHotpointAction()
6. DJIGoHomeAction()

When i am trying with **DJI Mavic Pro** then mission is executed successfully but same sequence i am trying with **Phantom 4** and it is not executing at all. Moreover i am not getting any error with Phantom 4 device.

**Phantom 4 is standing at one place after executing GoToAction() and not able to execute DJIGimbalAttitudeAction()**.

Here is my sample code:-

```
func createTimeline() {

            let goToAction = DJIGoToAction(coordinate: coordinate, altitude: kTargetAltitude)

            // DJIShootPhotoAction works if there is SD card available in the drone
            // The captured photo can be read from SD card
            let shootPhotoAction = DJIShootPhotoAction()

            let continuousShootPhotoAction = DJIShootPhotoAction(photoCount: 24, timeInterval: 3.0, waitUntilFinish: false)

            let hotPointMission1 = self.defaultHotPointAction(location: coordinate, altitude: kTargetAltitude, radius: Float(20.0))!

            let gimbalAction1 = DJIGimbalAttitudeAction(attitude: DJIGimbalAttitude(pitch: -90.0, roll: 0.0, yaw: 0.0))
            gimbalAction1?.completionTime = 2

            let returmHomeAction = DJIGoHomeAction()

            timelineActions = [ goToAction,  shootPhotoAction,  continuousShootPhotoAction,  hotPointMission1, returmHomeAction] as! [DJIMissionControlTimelineElement]

}


func startTimeline() {
                    self.addListenerForTimelineUpdates()

                    self.startTakeoff(completion: { (error) in
                        guard error == nil else { return }

                        logText += "\n start timeline"
                        DJISDKManager.missionControl()?.scheduleElements(timelineElements)
                        DJISDKManager.missionControl()?.startTimeline()
                    })
}

func addListenerForTimelineUpdates() {

        DJISDKManager.missionControl()?.addListener(self, toTimelineProgressWith: { (event, element, error, info) in
            guard error == nil else { return }

            print("### \n\n Event: \(event.rawValue) \n Element:\(String(describing: element)) \n Error: \(String(describing: error)) \n Info: \(String(describing: info)) \n\n ")

            //once event is finished, stop the timeline and initiate return home
            if event.rawValue == DJIMissionControlTimelineEvent.finished.rawValue && element == nil {
                logText += "DJIMissionControlTimelineEvent.finished, stop timeline and remove listeners"
                DJISDKManager.missionControl()?.removeAllListeners()
                DJISDKManager.missionControl()?.stopTimeline()
            }
        })
    }
}
```

I tried my best but not able to fix this. I am working with DJI IOS SDK 4.10/4.11 & Xcode 10.2.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: doesnt` looks like ur code issue. more likely to be dji sdk issue. send a ticket to dev@dji.com

Comment: @DrYuanShenghai, have you got any idea where it is doing wrong in the Timeline mission? I also raised ticket to dev@dji.com, now waiting for their reply.

Comment: well i would guess to be a firmware compatibility issue. for example, DJI a3 when loading firmware 1.7.5 and running with osdk 3.8, the mission can not execute, the drone just stuck. when load 1.7.7, then the mission will carry out. i guess you are experiencing a similar issue